# Pandas pivots index as columns using groupby-apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have come across some strange behavior in Pandas groupby-apply that I am trying to figure out.
Take the following example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = range(1, 11)
groups = ["A", "B"]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([index, groups], names = ["index", "group"])

np.random.seed(12)
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": np.random.normal(size=len(idx))}, index=idx).reset_index()

print(df.tail().round(2))

        index group   val
15      8     B     -0.12
16      9     A      1.01
17      9     B     -0.91
18     10     A     -1.03
19     10     B      1.21
```

And using this framework (which allows me to execute any arbitrary function within a groupby-apply):

```
def add_two(x):
    return x + 2

def pd_groupby_apply(df, out_name, in_name, group_name, index_name, function):
    
    def apply_func(df):
        if index_name is not None:
            df = df.set_index(index_name).sort_index()
            
        df[out_name] = function(df[in_name].values)
        
        return df[out_name]
    
    return df.groupby(group_name).apply(apply_func)
```

Whenever I call `pd_groupby_apply` with the following inputs, I get a pivoted DataFrame:

```
df_out1 = pd_groupby_apply(df=df, 
                           out_name="test", 
                           in_name="val", 
                           group_name="group", 
                           index_name="index", 
                           function=add_two)
print(df_out1.head().round(2))

index    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10
group                                                            
A      2.47  2.24  2.75  2.01  1.19  1.40  3.10  3.34  3.01  0.97
B      1.32  0.30  0.47  1.88  4.87  2.47  0.78  1.88  1.09  3.21
```

However, as soon as my dataframe does not contain full group-index pairs, and I call my `pd_groupby_apply` function again,  I do recieve my dataframe back in the way that I want (i.e. not pivoted):

```
df_notfull = df.iloc[:-1]

df_out2 = pd_groupby_apply(df=df_notfull, 
                           out_name="test", 
                           in_name="val", 
                           group_name="group", 
                           index_name="index", 
                           function=add_two)
print(df_out2.head().round(2))

group  index
A      1        2.47
       2        2.24
       3        2.75
       4        2.01
       5        1.19
```

Why is this? And more importantly, how can I prevent Pandas from pivoting my dataframe when I have full index-group pairs in my dataframe?

Comment: It seems that this is a [known](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31063) issue.